# Putting hyperlinked and non-hyperlinked text in one line, centered, on .php

Tags: php

My code for my footer is:

```
<?php echo "<font color=#ffffff>Copyright © 2016 EXAMPLE |</font></p>"; ?> <?php echo "<a href=privacy-policy><font color=#0080ff>Privacy Policy</font></a></p>"; ?> <?php "<font color=#ffffff> / </font>"; ?>  <?php echo "<a href=terms-of-use><font color=#0080ff> Terms of Use</font></a>"; ?>
```

I want it to look like this (centered):

```
      Copyright © 2016 EXAMPLE | Privacy Policy | Terms of Use
```

if the vertical bar can't be used there, you can suggest. Thanks.

Comment: it's a messy code.. lol. I'm just starting out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a WordPress specific question but here's what you'll likely want to do. Notice also the example below is using the PHP `date` function which will dynamically update the year:

**style.css**

```
.copyright {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.copyright a {
  color: #0080ff;
}
```

**footer.php**

```
<div class="copyright">
  Copyright &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> EXAMPLE | 
  <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a> | 
  <a href="#">Terms of Use</a>
</div>
```